# How do I create an async CRUD function that create a user, generate a token and login the user in node.js and Postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, pg-promise

NOTE: I am using node.js, express.js, Postgres and pg-promise library.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want the *createUser* function to create a new user with a hashed password, generate a token and login the user. I want to be able to see the token generated in Postman so that I will know if the code is working fine.

**WHAT I AM CURRENTLY SEEING**

I am seeing an empty {} array when I tested my code in Postman. On testing, the user is created in the Postgres database as expected, but the response in postman show {}. However, I wanted the response to display the success message and the token generated. I don't know if the problem is with the function not generating token. Find my code below:

**MY CURRENT CREATEUSER FUNCTION**

```
async createUser(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).send({'message': 'Some values are missing'});
    }
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const createuserquery = `insert into user_table(username, email, email_verified, password, role, created_at, last_login)
                  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, now(), now()) returning *`;
  const createuservalues = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.email_verified, hashedPassword, req.body.role];

  try {
    const result = await db.one(createuserquery, createuservalues);
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { username: result.rows[0].username }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' }
    );
  return res
    .status(200) 
    .cookie('jwt', token, {
      httpOnly: true
    })
    .json({
      success: true,
      data: data,
      message: 'One user created'
    });
} catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
}
```

I am suspecting the token const below:

```
const token = jwt.sign(
      { username: result.rows[0].username }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' }
    );
```

**OR**
The return res part below:

```
return res
    .status(200) 
    .cookie('jwt', token, {
      httpOnly: true
    })
    .json({
      success: true,
      data: data,
      message: 'One user created'
    });
} catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
```

**CHANGES SUGGESTED**
I made the change suggested by @TitusSutioFanpula but the result still display the empty array {} in postman

```
return res
    .status(200) 
    .cookie('jwt', token, {
      httpOnly: true
    })
    .json({
      success: true,
      data: { token },
      message: 'One user created'
    });
} catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
```

Comment: You can look at your code, where is `data` come from? your `data` in your `res`. You have to change `data` with `{ token }` then you will get your token

Comment: you want to create user + token + then get response data as user + token right ??

Comment: Yes I want to get the response back with the created token @Prakash Karena

Answer (score 0):

‍ From your code, I don't know where your `data` come from. But you can change the data with `token`.

**For an example**, you can look at this code below or you can change your response with this code below :

```js
try {
    const result = await db.one(createuserquery, createuservalues);
    const token = jwt.sign({ username: result.rows[0].username }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' });
    return res
      .status(200) 
      .cookie('jwt', token, {
        httpOnly: true
      })
      .json({
        success: true,
        data: { token },
        message: 'One user created'
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      return res.status(500).send('Something failed');
    }
```

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: I made the change suggested by @TitusSutioFanpula but the result still display the empty array {} in postman

Comment: can't be empty, if it's right, because in there, you have some string in message, or boolean in success. So, make sure, the endpoin you call is the right endpoint.

Comment: First, make sure to send a simple response like this. res.status(200).send('success'). Make sure it's working. If it's still not working, than something wrong with your endpoint was you call.

Comment: Or the last thing is try to add `res.status(500).send('Something Failed')` in your catch. I think maybe the empty array it's come from your catch block. **I've been update my answer, you can try it**

Comment: Thanks @TitusSutioFanpula.  I added the ```res.status(200).send('success')``` code as you suggested and also the ```res.status(500).send('Something Failed')```. In both instances, the user get created and added to the database but instead of showing the token, it display the catch error message ('Something Failed').

Comment: So, now you can console.log the error in the catch block. And try to fix it by your self. If you need any help, dont forget to reply this comment.

Comment: I am getting the error ```Cannot read property '0' of undefined``` in the console. Is it suggesting that the token is not being created?

Comment: You can console log your result first, what the object you get. And then get the field you want if the object exists

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean in the last comment on console log first. Where should I do that?

Comment: You have `result` variabel right? You can console.log in the below of that variabel.